# Upload big videos from a form to server - PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, chunks, plupload

I have to set up a form allowing the upload of videos whose weight is about 20GB for each.

This processing must be done in PHP.

I did a test with [Plupload](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload), but it does not work very well beyond 100MB: the file is uploaded, but its data is unusable (cf screenshot).

Do you have any recommendations/best practices?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: If you uploading the file over CF network in Free plan, it wont work. 100MB is the limit try upgrading CF Plan.
or
You can try chunked file upload which can bypass CF limit and which is very speedy but Which corrupt the file.

kindly check your php.ini file upload limit too.

Comment: Thanks, I test directly locally, so no limitations other than php.ini (configured to 500MB)

Comment: Did you increased post_max_size = 500MB and upload_max_filesize = 500MB ? in php.ini

Comment: yes: 
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '500M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '500M');

Comment: Please check plupload has any file size limit and check php, web server logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the solution, in your .js file that handle the upload you just need to add the multipart option and to put the value to false :)

It means that the chunk should be sent as binary stream (ie. multipart : false) and not as multipart/form-data (default ie. multipart : true)

If need here is an example on how I handled video files upload with Plupload :
https://github.com/Rapkalin/bigupload

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

At first point you need to make some changes in your php.ini configuration file. Look for **upload_max_filesize**, **post_max_size**, then you should look for **max_execution_time**, **max_input_time**. As i can see your file is missing an extension, easiest and fastest way to handle this is:

```
$strpos = strpos($file, '.');
if (!$strpos) return false;
$name = substr($file, 0, $strpos);
$ext  = substr($file, ($strpos + 1));
```

Now you can encode your name and append extension later. Also it will be good to paste your script or sample so we can look at it.

Comment: thanks for your time, it was a problem with Multipart Option